# Powershell - Bytes sent/received

Tags: powershell

I need to create a script that samples the network traffic every 30 seconds and stores the bytes sent/received. This data is then later used to draw graphs. I wrote one that works perfectly on Windows 2012 but i realised some of the cmdlets were not available in previous versions like 2008 so i am seeking alternatives.

For windows 2012 i used get-netadapterstatistics to get the received/sent bytes but this won't work on pre 2012 so i thought i could use netstat -e but the problem is both are giving me completely different results and i was hoping someone can tell me why? The script below was written to see the different between data.

```
function getNic{
$nic = Get-NetRoute | ? DestinationPrefix -eq '0.0.0.0/0' | Get-NetIPInterface | Where ConnectionState -eq "Connected" | Select -ExpandProperty InterfaceAlias
return $nic
}

function getBR{
   $b = ((netstat -e | Select-String "Bytes") -split '\s+')[2]
   $a = (Get-NetAdapterStatistics |Where InterfaceAlias -eq $nic_name   |Select -ExpandProperty SentBytes)

   $a - $script:startbr
   $b - $script:startbr2
   $script:startbr = $a
   $script:Startbr2 = $b

}


$nic_name = getNic
$startbr = (Get-NetAdapterStatistics |Where InterfaceAlias -eq    $nic_name |Select -ExpandProperty SentBytes)
 $startbr2 = ((netstat -e | Select-String "Bytes") -split '\s+')[2]

for(1..1000){
    getBR

    Start-Sleep 5
}
```

The results are as below

```
0
0
4577
18308
6695
26780
9055
36220
```

Ideally i am only interested in capturing traffic on the external interface.

Comment: Hi, `4577 * 4 = 18308`, had you noticed ?

Comment: No i had not, but i ran it again to see if that is consistent but it seems not. Am i doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While i can´t offer you an explanation for the difference between your methods i could offer you an alternative that should work on pre 2012 as well as on 2012 upwards:

```
$ifIndex = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ip4routetable | where {$_.destination -eq "0.0.0.0"} | select -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex
$ifIndex = "InterfaceIndex=" + $ifIndex
$nic_name = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Filter $ifIndex | select -ExpandProperty Description
$nic = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.Networkinterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() | where {($_.description -eq $nic_name) -and ($_.operationalstatus -eq "up")}
$stats = $nic.GetIPv4Statistics()
$bytesSent = $stats.BytesSent
$bytesReceived = $stats.BytesReceived
```

This gives results consistent with the `Get-NetAdapterStatistics` Cmdlet on my system

After thinking about it maybe `netstat` shows statistics for multiple network adapters (maybe including loopback) combined since there is no differentiation by nic? Just guessing but this might explain the increased bytecount. Sadly there´s no details to be found in the docs

Comment: One more question. The way i am retrieving the name of the NIC is through get-netroute again this won't work on pre 2012 or a certain powershell version. Is there a way for me to find the NIC with default route set, and monitor statistics on that interface only. So far i have come across many different methods but it seems each either gives me a Index number, a name or description which is different in the other commands.

Comment: OK i have finally found a way. Thanks for all the help.